# KendoUI grid does not fire saveChanges event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with events in KendoUI grid control. I assigned "saveChanges" event after grid initialization. I use popup for data editing. I want to fire event "saveChanges" when the user pushes "Save" button. Unfortunately the event is not fired. I can't figure out what is the problem, moreover,  other events work. The grid is initialized within MVC helpers. Events are assigned in JavaScript.

Here is the JavaScript code that I'm using:

```
 function bindGridEvents() {
        var that = this;

        //kendoGrid is an abbreviation of: $("#grid").data("kendoGrid")

        kendoGrid.bind("dataBound", function () { }); // works
        kendoGrid.bind("edit", function (event) { }); // works
        kendoGrid.dataSource.bind("error", function (event) {}); // works
        kendoGrid.bind("saveChanges", function (event) { console.log("This event is not fired!"); });
        kendoGrid.bind("save", function (event) { }); // works
    }
```

I've already spent a lot of time for finding the solution on my own without success. I will appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

I have found what the problem was. Documentation says:

> saveChanges event is fired when the user clicks the "save" command
>   button.

But when the popup shows the command with label "Save" is of type "update". That is why it does not work in edit mode. It works in toolbar only. It's not obvious at first and the documention don't say too much so be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code I can't be sure. The event will not fire without you doing any changes    I believe. Nice example which works for me is [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-saveChanges). If you dealing with the actual dataItem edit not via the grid features, make sure you mark the item as "dirty". Ideally post your code as JsFiddle or JSBin.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I've just found the cause.